# iPhone Lite version - what is allowed?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm scratching my head over this.

I have a moderately successful app which has a free "LITE" version in addition to the full one. This is a utility app, not a game with levels, and I'm having trouble figuring out what Apple will accept for the lite version. The reason this is now an issue is that I've brought both code bases together with different targets and my new improved lite version will be iPad compatible as well.

There are two fundamental differences in the versions. In the lite version, the data displayed is only displayed for the current day, whereas the full version allows users to choose any date. Additionally, one of the data screens shows 3 data points in detail, whereas the full version shows much more. The lite version is perfectly functional in its own right and has no greyed out features.

What I would like to do is use the spare space on the lite version data screen to explain that more data is available in the full version and offer a button to upgrade, however I can't figure out if Apple will classify this as "upselling" (well how else am I going to mention the full version?) and from reading the new app store review guidelines, I was disappointed to note that absolutely no further clarity seems forthcoming from Cupertino in this regard. All the examples I find from Apple are games with additional levels and this simply doesn't match a "utility" application.

Is there any recent advice on what is and what is not allowed? I'm aware of not having greyed out functionality and nagging the user - but does having an upgrade button on one of the tabs (in the case of the iPad in a popover) count as nagging? Am I allowed to mention the additional features in the premium version or does that count as upselling? If not, what can I actually say?

Clues welcomed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frankly speaking, there is no way to be 100% sure without submitting the app. There might be someone who have already tried this and get rejected. It's not very easy to be sure. But as a user personally I won't be happy to see the upgrade button in every page. Rather I would like to get the summery of full version in a different page. This might not be a better design to have an upgrade button in every page, though this is my personal opinion. Apple gives importance to be consistent with the convention, and the convention is to have different upgrade page, I think.

You can download a number of lite apps and check whether any one has done this kind of thing. The policy should be same for both game and utility. If after checking many you don't find a single one, then you should reconsider this. But yes, you can't be 100% sure.

Comment: +1 "there is no way to be 100% sure without submitting the app" - definitely, especially when submitting an update that gets rejected is effectively costless. I'm not sure what the typical rejection percentage is, but it's not uncommon.

Comment: @tc submitting an update that gets rejected is only costless if your time isn't worth anything. But I agree that this is unfortunately, often the only way to know for sure.

Answer (score 4):

The rules appear to be inconsistently applied.

I think it boils down to the perceived difference between "Ha! You don't get $feature unless you pay us!" and "By the way, we also offer $more_expensive_app with more features." The two are effectively the same thing, but they leave a different impression. Yes, it's a big grey area — I've seen apps across the spectrum (I don't recall any persistent nagging/mentions, but certainly "buy $full_app to get more levels").

"Other apps by $company" might be a good way to go, perhaps in an "about" tab or similar.

Reviewers are also far from consistent. Before Apple did any "private API" checks (they didn't seem to until mid-2009; apparently not even the frameworks you linked to which is dead easy), private API usage was determined by whether your app did anything in $list_of_suspicious_behaviour, which seemed to be applied inconsistently by different reviewers.

I've also used "$full_app" because that's the impression I got; I think part of the guidelines is that you're not supposed to give the impression that your app is not "full". I also hate crippleware (artificially limiting a feature, e.g. a navigation app limited to 8 waypoints and telling you to buy the full version if you want more, as opposed to simply not including a feature), but Apple doesn't seem to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Apple allows ads in apps if they are presented in a reasonable manner.

Developers can choose which ad network to run, even from competitors such as admob.

There's nothing to say you can't be your own ad network.

Just make sure your ad for your products (which occasionally just so happens to be an ad for the full version of the same app) follows the same presentation rules as the ads for admob, iAd, etc. follow.  Your own ad network may or may not be the campaign you choose to run during the review period.